# Concatenate data according to a partial numeric match

Tags: r, string-concatenation

i have two data frames.

one is structured like this:

```
  code.  name.  
  1111   A B  
  1122   C D
  2122   C D
  2133   G H
```

the other is:

```
 code_2.  name.  
  11       F
  21       G
```

i want to obtain a third df that, in relation to code match, concatenate my data present in the first data frame, using a "OR" separator. The code value that I want to mantain is the the one of the second df. It is important that the match among code values would be made **on the first and second number of the code** belonging to the first dataframe.

```
 code.     name.  
  11     A B OR C D
  21     C D OR G H
```

thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Where did `name` of second data frame go?

Comment: We can delete it. It is not important anymore

Comment: So you don't really need the second data frame. Just substring the first two characters from the first df, group by them and concatenate `name`...

Comment: maybe I should omit it from the beginning. Sorry for the ingenuity.

Comment: Yes, I get what you are saying but I'm not probably able to replicate it properly by myself. Could you please answer the question? thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `aggregate`, i.e.

```
aggregate(name. ~ substr(code., 1, 2), df, paste, collapse = ' OR ')
#  substr(code., 1, 2)      name.
#1                  11 A B OR C D
#2                  21 C D OR G H
```

You can take care of the column names as usual.

Comment: To change the column names, add `~ cbind(code. = substr(code., 1, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer `tidyverse`, you can try something like:

```
df %>%
 group_by(code. = str_extract(as.character(code.), "^.{2}")) %>%
 summarise(name. = paste(name., collapse = " OR "))

  code. name.     
  <chr> <chr>     
1 11    A B OR C D
2 21    C D OR G H
```

It groups by the first two elements from "code." and then combines the "name." column based on those elements.

Or the same using `sub()`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(code. = sub("^(.{2}).*", "\\1", as.character(code.))) %>%
 summarise(name. = paste(name., collapse = " OR "))
```

Or the same using `substring()`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(code. = substring(as.character(code.), 1, 2)) %>%
 summarise(name. = paste(name., collapse = " OR "))
```